# C++ System Command window shows up when launching a WinForm Application

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ - based application. This application triggers in turn a C# based WinForm executable. I use system() to launch this. When I do this, I get system (command prompt) window alongwith my form.  My question is how to suppress this window.  I want only to launch the application without prompt window...

```
// Trigger the form application
system("C:\\tmp\\MyApp\\SBCForm.exe");
```

Comment: Show the code you use in the system command

Comment: Try using c# Process.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094428/using-c-sharp-process-to-run-a-executable-program

Comment: Nope... I am launching it from C++ application... using method system()... I need something in C++...

Comment: Look the 1st answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278641/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-in-c

Comment: The system() function runs the command processor, cmd.exe.  Which is a console mode app so you'll get a console window.  Lose system(), use CreateProcess() or one of the _exec functions.