# C# - Executing external exectutable with arguments

Tags: c#, python

I have been trying to convert my python code to c# code. For some reason, the c# code gets to the DirectoryInfo declaration and says the path is not found. If someone can tell me why, it would be appreciated.

This is the original python code:

```
def encode(path, dest):
     for root_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):

        for name in files:
            (base, ext)=os.path.splitext(name)
            input_file = os.path.join(root_dir,name)
            output_file = os.path.join(dest_dir, base+".mkv")
            if (os.path.exists(output_file)):
                 print ("skipped")
            else:
                 subprocess.call( ["HandBrakeCLI.exe", "-i", input_file, "-o", output_file, "-e", "x264", "--aencoder", "ac3", "-s", "1", "--subtitle-default", "1" ])
```

This is my current c# code:

```
string qpath = Path.GetFullPath((Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Queue\\"));
if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(qpath)))
{
    var DirMKV = (Directory.GetFiles(qpath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mkv") || s.EndsWith(".mp4")).ToArray());
    foreach (string file in DirMKV)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(file);
        if (dirinfo.Parent.Parent.ToString().Contains("S"))
        {
            string ipath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string dpath = ipath + @"\Queue\" + dirinfo.Parent.Parent.ToString() + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
            string opath = ipath + @"\Finished\" + dirinfo.Parent.Parent.ToString() + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
            string arg = "-i " +dpath + " -o " +opath +" -e  x264 "+ " --aencoder ac3 "+ "-s 1 "+ "--subtitle-default 1";
            if (!File.Exists(opath))
            {
                Process.Start(ipath + @"\handbrakeCLI.exe", arg);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is it failing on? What path is it trying to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094428/using-c-sharp-process-to-run-a-executable-program

Comment: Without knowing which error you get, is pretty impossible to solve this. BUT, you are escaping characters twice, like here: `ipath + @"\\Finished\\"` it should be ` \\ ` or ` @"\" `

Comment: Ok. Update: when executed the processes are launched then close immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand Python, but from what I see, your c# code and python code definitely do different things. There are bunch of things that are not clear. I have commented your code with my advice. Hopefully that will solve your issues

**Commented code below**

```
string qpath = Path.GetFullPath((Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Queue\\"));
if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(qpath))) // No need to do Path.GetFullPath again
{
    var DirMKV = (Directory.GetFiles(qpath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mkv") || s.EndsWith(".mp4")).ToArray()); // no need to do ToArray. List all files in Queue folder
    foreach (string file in DirMKV)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(file); // I don't get any Path not found exception here
        if (dirinfo.Parent.Parent.ToString().Contains("S")) // Check if GrandParent directory name contains the letter S. Don't see any such thing in python code
        {
            string ipath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string dpath = ipath + @"\\Queue\\" + dirinfo.Parent.Parent.ToString() + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file); // Set input file to something like Queue\*S*\File.mkv. Does this file exist??? It should use single backslash instead of double backslash
            string opath = ipath + @"\\Finished\\" + dirinfo.Parent.Parent.ToString() + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file); // Set output file to something like Finished\*S*\File.mkv. It should use single backslash instead of double backslash
            string arg = "-i " +dpath + " -o " +opath +" -e  x264 "+ " --aencoder ac3 "+ "-s 1 "+ "--subtitle-default 1";
            if (!File.Exists(opath))
            {
                Process.Start(ipath + @"\handbrakeCLI.exe", arg); // does the handbrakeCLI.exe exist in the current directory????
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

**Below code is based on my guess about what you want**

```
/*
    * Expects a directory structure like below
    * S
    * |-> bin
    *      |-> Queue
    *             |-> test1.mp4
    *             |-> test2.mkv
    *      |-> Finished
    *             |-> test3.mkv
    *      |-> executable (this code)
    *      |-> handbrakeCLI.exe
    * 
    */
DirectoryInfo qpath = new DirectoryInfo("Queue");
if (qpath.Exists) {
    var mkvFiles = qpath.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.Extension == ".mkv" || s.Extension == ".mp4");
    foreach (var mkvFile in mkvFiles) {
        var gParent = mkvFile.Directory.Parent.ToString();
        if (gParent.Contains("S")) {
            string opath = Path.Combine(mkvFile.Directory.Parent.FullName, "Finished", mkvFile.Name);
            string arg = "-i " + mkvFile.FullName + " -o " + opath + " -e  x264 " + " --aencoder ac3 " + "-s 1 " + "--subtitle-default 1";
            if (!File.Exists(opath))
                Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory+ @"\handbrakeCLI.exe", arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just need to fix the errors I'm getting with handbrake.

Comment: I am guessing that the input file does not exist for handbrake which is causing the early exit